# Using jade.compile to compile a jade template that is a mixin file or has partials included

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I'm trying to figure out how to do this.

Problem: I'm trying to compile a jade template for my email campaign but the file I'm trying to compile is a mixin which includes some partial.

e.g.:

**controllers/user.js:**

```
var emailTemplate = jade.compile(fs.readFileSync('./views/emails/new_user.jade', 'utf8'), { filename: './views/emails/new_user.jade'});

  var template = emailTemplate({
      baseUrl: res.locals.baseUrl,
      confirmCode: user.confirmCode,
      siteLogo: config.siteLogo,
      name: user.username,
      email: user.email
    });
```

**./views/emails/new_user.jade:**

```
include ../mixins/emails
div(style='margin-bottom: 20px; border: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 20px; width: 50%; margin: 0 auto 20px;')
  div(style='text-align: center; border-bottom: 1px solid #EEE; padding-bottom: 10px;')
    img(src='#{siteLogo}', style='text-align: center;')
  p
    | Hi #{name},
  p
    | Please confirm your account
  div(style='background-color: #179159; border-bottom: 1px solid #16814F; display: block; float: left; margin-bottom: 20px; text-align: center;       width: 100%;') 
  mixin button('test')
```

**./views/emails/mixins/emails.jade:**

```
mixin button(text)
button
  =text
```

It looks like renderFile in jade.compile only opens one at a time, unfortunately.

https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/blob/master/jade.js#L950

Is there a way that I can do what I want (which is open new_user.jade which contains mixins) or do I have to do something like:

- modify the renderFile source and change it to accept an array
- do an fs.readFileSync() on the file
- parse each line at the top checking for `include`
- then open each of those files
- concat them into one .jade file

or something crazy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the source

```
exports.renderFile = function(path, options, fn){
  ...
  var str = options.cache
    ? exports.cache[key] || (exports.cache[key] = fs.readFileSync(path, 'utf8'))
    : fs.readFileSync(path, 'utf8');
  return exports.render(str, options);
};
```

*cache is **disable** by default, so you should not modify renderFile*

**to enable cache:**

```
renderFile('path/to/file.jade', {cache: true})
```

I do not know exactly your problem, but you need to separate *compile-time* and *render-time*. If you mean your jade files are changed during process, so you need to recompile them.

**define mixin**

```
mixin button(text)
  button= text
```

**To call a mixin**

```
+button('test')
```

Comment: My problem (which your suggestion won't fix) is that I can't render a jade file from my controller that contains a mixin inside of it.

Comment: can you compile it? Check the way you call mixin.

Comment: you may miss tab or space when define mixin?

Comment: I know how to include/call a mixin. I'm getting the following error because compile() only opens one file at a time it seems (and by looking at its code, appears)... `unexpected token "indent"`

Comment: You may have spaces or tab before 'mixin button(text)', remove it, and make sure, use only tabs, or only space, not both

Comment: Man, I totally thought I got rid of all of the spaces. Turns out there was one within the mixin itself after the declaration. Looks like it works now, so thank you!